# Delphi custom generic list

Tags: delphi, generics

Can somebody please tell me why I am getting the

> Incompatible type: 'TChild' and 'Class of TChild'

```
 TBase = class (TObject)
 end;

 TMyList<T: TBase> = class(TObjectList<T>)
 end;
```

The error comes when I declare a child from the base class and try to create a list of TChild.

```
TChild = class (TBase)
end;

TChildList = TMyList<TChild>;
```

Comment: I don't think you've shown the real code. Please show SSCCE. Please also ask one question at a time.

Comment: I dont get any errors here. I litterally copied the code you posted. Added a property to TBase called Id, made a Tchildlist and added 4 tchilds. No proplems at all.

Answer (score 4):

The code in the question is fine. Here is proof, a complete program that compiles:

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  System.Generics.Collections;

type
  TBase = class (TObject)
  end;

  TMyList<T: TBase> = class(TObjectList<T>)
  end;

  TChild = class (TBase)
  end;

  TChildList = TMyList<TChild>;

begin
end.
```

Clearly you need to edit the question to post code that exhibits the fault. Feel free to use the above as a template for how to provide a Delphi language [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: Thanks at-least your example has showed me the error was not in the place that i was thinking it to be. 
The compiler was giving error in a different place. I wanted to know the type of data that my list class holds and I was returning the type as a property. 
`type
   TBaseList<T: TBaseClass> = class(TObjectList<T>)
   private
     function get__Type: T;
   public
     property _Type: T read get__Type;
   end;`
this was causing the error. If i remove this property then the code works fine. Do you know how i can get the class type that a list holds.

Comment: I'd be happy to answer this question if you asked it as a question. It seems clear what is wrong. The property has type `T`. That means the property holds an instance of type `T`. You would need the property to be of type `class of T` to return a meta class. I showed you in my answer how to write an SSCCE. Please do follow that lead and ask your question as either a new question or an edit, but giving a proper SSCCE.